# How to get the name of the day in a week using DateTimePicker

Tags: java, android

I want to get the name of the day like (Monday,Tuesday, etc.) after selected in the DateTimePicker

```
DatePickerDialog  datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog (RegisterStudent.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");

            //this is where I getting the wrong results it gives me thursday only even if i changethe day
            String dayName=simpleDateFormat.format(i2);


            _dob.setText(String.valueOf(dayName+","+ getMonthForInt(i1) +" " +datePicker.getDayOfMonth()+ ", " + i));

        }
    },mYear,mMonth,mDay);
```

I can get the name of the months through this

```
  private String getMonthForInt(int num) {
    String month = "wrong";
    DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols();
    String[] months = dfs.getMonths();
    if (num >= 0 && num <= 11 ) {
        month = months[num];
    }
    return month;

}
```

Expected Result

```
 Monday, Januar 12, 2019
 Tuesday, October 13, 2020
```

Result that I get

```
 Thursday, Januar 12, 2019
 Thursday, October 13, 2020//always thursday
```

Comment: Create a var and pass that as ref. Or take ref out in which you should.

Comment: Which line is the compiler pointing the error to?

Comment: Hi, please reopen my question so it can be answerd. I edited today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the ref keyword in your class's constructor, so when you instantiate the class you need to include the ref keyword in the parameters.

Like this:

```
 try
        {
            string test = "COM1";
            SMSCOMMS SMSEngine = new SMSCOMMS(ref test);
            SMSEngine.Open();
            SMSEngine.SendSMS("09xxxxxxxxx", "THIS IS YOUR MESSAGE");
            SMSEngine.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ee) {
            MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason for `COMMPORT` to passed as `ref`

Just edit the class, and problem solved

```
public SMSCOMMS(string COMMPORT)
```